# Why does a backward range search not start from the end?

Tags: swift, regex, string

I've tried the following regular expression search in swift playground:

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

if let match = greeting.range(of: "o", options: [.backwards, .regularExpression]) {

    print("Lower \(match.lowerBound) upper \(match.upperBound)")
    let lower = greeting.substring(to: match.lowerBound)
    let upper = greeting.substring(from: match.lowerBound)

    print("lower '\(lower)' upper '\(upper)'")
}
```

The output of this playground is:

```
Lower Index(_rawBits: 262157) upper Index(_rawBits: 327693)
lower 'Hell' upper 'o, playground'
```

While I don't understand at all the representation of the lower/upper bounds (I thought they were indices, but they look like some internal pointer values), my expectation was that the first lower substring would be `Hello, playgr`, since I specified the `.backwards` option. In fact, it doesn't matter if I have the `.backwards`, the result is the same if I put this option or not.

Why does the range function not find the first `o` letter from the end of the string and instead finds the first one?

Comment: Read the docs for [`.regularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1410450-regularexpression): *"The search string is treated as an ICU-compatible regular expression. If set, no other options can apply except caseInsensitive and anchored."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `.regularExpression` mentions:

> The search string is treated as an ICU-compatible regular expression. If set, no other options can apply except caseInsensitive and anchored.

Thus, the `.backwards` option is ignored completely and the search is always done from the start of the string. By modifying the regular expression the intended effect can be obtained:

```
import UIKit

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

if let match = greeting.range(of: ".*o", options: [.regularExpression]) {

    print("Lower \(match.lowerBound) upper \(match.upperBound)")
    //let sub = inputUrl.substring(from: match.upperBound)
    let lower = greeting.substring(to: match.upperBound)
    let upper = greeting.substring(from: match.upperBound)

    print("lower '\(lower)' upper '\(upper)'")
}
```

Outputs:

```
Lower Index(_rawBits: 13) upper Index(_rawBits: 917517)
lower 'Hello, playgro' upper 'und'
```